# How can I do a render of the 3D Viewport, in Python, so it uses the shading style I've selected?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, 3d-view

I've found that I can't change the normal rendering, from a camera, to WIREFRAME, SOLID, or anything but RENDERED. (Actually, there isn't a setting to change, it just goes to RENDERED.) In the Python Console,I've done this:

[image]

First, I set a variable to the area that is the 3D Viewport for convenience. Then I check the shading and it's WIREFRAME. From there, I render that space, the 3D Viewport. It always renders from the default camera. My first test render rendered in the SOLID mode, but now I can't get it to render the 3D Viewport view (using `bpy.ops.render.opengl()`) and it always renders in RENDERED mode. Here's a sample - rather crowded and from the top:

[image]

I was under the impression that if I rendered the 3D Viewport space, I could get it to render in whatever shading method that was currently set for the Viewport. Is that not the case? Other than using plugins, is there a way to control the shading for rendering the view in the Viewport?

I'm beginning to think it just won't work, but I thought I saw instructions (that worked) that would let me do this and I've been searching, but can't find a way to do it.

So, bottom line, how can I specify the shading mode in the Viewport, render that view, then save the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`render.opengl()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=opengl#bpy.ops.render.opengl) operator is working fine for all modes. But notice that it takes a screenshot of the first viewport found, quoting the docs: *"Take a snapshot of the active viewport"*. So in case you have multiple 3d viewports open at the same time it takes the first one in the area list of your screen ([`Screen.Areas`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Screen.html?highlight=areas#bpy.types.Screen.areas)).

---

Obviously the simplest option is to *close all 3d viewports except one*, set the shading mode, call the operator and pass `write_still=True` to take the screenshot as well as saving the file into the default [*Output* directory](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/properties/output.html):

```
>>> bpy.ops.render.opengl(write_still=True)
```

In case you have multiple viewports open and you'd like to specify the area for the screenshot, you can [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) when calling [`render.opengl()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=opengl#bpy.ops.render.opengl) operator. See the following demo on how to find the first 3d viewport set to `'WIREFRAME'` and take a screenshot:

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        # Check for WIREFRAME, SOLID, RENDERED, MATERIAL
        if area.spaces.active.shading.type == 'WIREFRAME':
            with C.temp_override(area=area):
                bpy.ops.render.opengl(write_still=True)
            break
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type=='VIEW_3D':
        # Check for WIREFRAME, SOLID, RENDERED, MATERIAL
        # area.spaces.active.shading.type
        if area.spaces.active.shading.type == 'WIREFRAME':
            override = C.copy()
            override['area'] = area
            bpy.ops.render.opengl(override, write_still=True)
            break
```

In order to set the filename, just temporary assign your path to the [`RenderSettings.filepath`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=render%20filepath#bpy.types.RenderSettings.filepath) property. Demo on how to take a screenshot of the first viewport found set to `'WIREFRAME'` and save the result to the *directory of the current blend* file:

**Blender 3.2+**

```
file_path = bpy.path.abspath("//screenshot")

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type=='VIEW_3D':
        if area.spaces.active.shading.type == 'WIREFRAME':
            
            # Store the current output path and set it
            temp = C.scene.render.filepath
            C.scene.render.filepath = file_path

            with C.temp_override(area=area):
                bpy.ops.render.opengl(write_still=True)

            # Restore the output path
            C.scene.render.filepath = temp
            break

print (file_path)
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
file_path = bpy.path.abspath("//screenshot")

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type=='VIEW_3D':
        if area.spaces.active.shading.type == 'WIREFRAME':
            # Store the current output path and set it
            temp = C.scene.render.filepath
            C.scene.render.filepath = file_path
            
            override = C.copy()
            override['area'] = area
            bpy.ops.render.opengl(override, write_still=True)
            
            # Restore the output path
            C.scene.render.filepath = temp
            break
            
print (file_path)
```

Comment: I'll have to check, but I think the screenshot is wrong. When testing, I had one camera set as the prime camera (can't remember the proper term now - ctrl-numpad-0) and it was rendering from that camera, not from the screenshot of the current view. Like I said, I'll have to check on it and see if I was doing something else I didn't realize was interfering.

Comment: An interesting note on this. I copied it into a text file in Blender and ran it with no trouble and got the output file, but when I did piece by piece in the console and got to the line to render the image, when I hit <return> nothing happened - it didn't move to the next line or anything. Just found that weird.